# SELECT Query runs fine but throws an error when used as source for REPLACE INTO

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a query, that runs fine on its own:

```
SELECT * FROM tabA WHERE colA != '--';
```

Now I would like to use it as a source for a `REPLACE INTO` statement. The query looks like the following:

```
REPLACE INTO tabB
SELECT * FROM tabA WHERE colA != '--';
```

Even though the `SELECT` part is exactly the same, now the query returns the following error:

> Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '--'

The column in question (tabA.colA) is defined as `BIGINT(20) NOT NULL` which means, it cannot be `--`. The condition should therefore always evaluate tom `true`

What is wrong with the query?

I'm using MySQL 5.7.

SQL Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hajQcShWrpfT1VbFr1s4nc/0

Comment: `colA` have BIGINT datatype. It cannot be compared with string type literal `'--'` which cannot be correctly converted to BIGINT. Converted **BEFORE** compare.

Comment: Under what circumstances does such a comparison arise? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-) +1 for a nice question - with a fiddle! If only all new posters took the time to make the effort (sigh...).

Comment: @Vérace found that in existing code, and from the looks of it, under some conditions it seems to actually work. Will remove the condition and replace it with something more sensible anyway